# Перезагрузка скрипта при изменении размера окна

Tags: javascript, media-queries

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    const article = $('.article'),
          nav = $('.aside-menu'),
          underheader = $('.underheader-fixed'),
          underheaderHeight = underheader.outerHeight(); // получаем высоту блока

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        const position = $(this).scrollTop();

        article.each(function () {
            const top = $(this).offset().top - underheaderHeight - 5,
                  bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

            if (position >= top && position <= bottom) {
                nav.find('a').removeClass('active-scroll');
                nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active-scroll');
            }
        });
    });

    nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
        const id = $(this).attr('href');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - underheaderHeight
        }, 1000);

        return false;
    });

});
```

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {font-size: 36px; margin: 0;}

.top-block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 0.05em solid white;
  background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#top-block-1 {
  z-index: 101;
}

#top-block-2 {
  top: 3em;
    z-index: 101;
}

.underheader {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
}

.underheader-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 6em;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 2em;
}

.main-section {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.post {
    position: relative;
    height: 30em;
  background-color: green;
}

.bw {
  background-color: red;
}

.aside-menu {
  background-color: #054a71;
  position: sticky;
  top: 8em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: 0.2em solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.aside-menu a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #054a71;
}

.aside-menu a.active-scroll,
.aside-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #0172b2
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
  #top-block-2 {
    display: none;
   }
  .underheader-fixed {
    height: 3em;
   }
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
  .sidebar {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  .aside-menu {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: inherit
    }
  .main-section {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <header class="head">
            <div id="top-block-1" class="top-block"></div>
            <div id="top-block-2" class="top-block"></div>
            <div class="underheader" id="underheader"></div>
            <div class="underheader-fixed"></div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="wrapper">
                <aside class="sidebar">
                    <nav class="aside-menu">
                        <a href="#anchor-scrl-1-diseases">первый</a>
                        <a href="#anchor-scrl-2-diseases">второй</a>
                        <a href="#anchor-scrl-3-diseases">третий</a>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
                <section class="main-section">
          <article class="post">
          </article>
          <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-1-diseases">
            <h1>первый</h1>
          </article>
          <article class="post article" id="anchor-scrl-2-diseases">
            <h1>второй</h1>
          </article>
          <article class="post bw article" id="anchor-scrl-3-diseases">
            <h1>третий</h1>
          </article>
        </section>
     </main>
</body>
```

Нужна помощь! Суть вопроса: у меня на сайте есть боковое меню, пункты которого скролят страницу к определенному якорю. При изменении размера окна, уменьшается размер шапки. Переход к якорю реализован через jquery. Чтобы верхняя часть якоря не пряталась под шапку, отступ от верха реализован через переменную, которая добавляет отступ от верхнего края соответственно размеру блока:

```
nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
    const id = $(this).attr('href');
    
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - underheaderHeight
    }, 1000);
    
    return false;
});
```

где `underheaderHeight` это переменная

```
const underheader = $('.underheader-fixed'),
      underheaderHeight = underheader.outerHeight();
```

размер блока `.underheader-fixed` меняется при медиа-запросе `@media (max-width: 980px)`. Если страницу перезагрузить, то все работает как положено, а вот если загрузить страницу и потом поменять размер окна, то страница перераспределяется соответственно медиа-запросу, а вот скрипт отрабатывает по первоначальным данным, перенося страницу со смещением.
Подскажите как правильно перезагрузить скрипт при изменении размера окна без перезагрузки всей страницы. Я нашел несколько кодов:

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 980) {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
              script.type = "text/javascript";
              script.src = "js/script.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };
});
```

либо путем выставления размера экрана в js и применения функции скрола внутри этой функции

```
window.matchMedia('(max-width: 980px)').addListener(function(e){
    if(e.matches) {
        //прописать функцию сюда
    }
});
```

Но добиться желаемого результата не смог. Нужна помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста предоставьте рабочий пример, или хотя бы полноценную часть вашего кода, у вас первая часть которая отрабатывает после клика, а снизу вообще не понятно что, и как это относится к вашей задаче, оформите ваш код

Comment: заранее спасибо за помощь. пример прикрепил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что высоту надо узнавать после действия (после скроллинга, после клика), а у вас получается то, что вы в underheaderHeight сохраняете высоту элемента после загрузки страницы, и то не факт, так как, у вас отсутствует событие **ready**, рекомендую обернуть ваш код

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(() => {
    ...
   }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Значит, узнавайте высоту underheader.outerHeight() по месту, смотрите пример

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Тут вы нашли элемент на странице
    const article = $('.article'),
          nav = $('.aside-menu'),
          underheader = $('.underheader-fixed');             

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        let underheaderHeight = underheader.outerHeight(); // получаем высоту блока
        const position = $(this).scrollTop();
        article.each(function () {
            const top = $(this).offset().top - underheaderHeight - 5,
                  bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

            if (position >= top && position <= bottom) {
                nav.find('a').removeClass('active-scroll');
                nav.find('a[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active-scroll');
            }
        });
    });

    nav.find('a').on('click', function () {
        let underheaderHeight = underheader.outerHeight(); // получаем высоту блока
        const id = $(this).attr('href');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - underheaderHeight
        }, 1000);

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Я не силен в js. Знал, что задаю переменную после загрузки, не знал, как задать после действия. Теперь всё работает как надо! Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
underheaderHeight = underheader.outerHeight()
```

Вы находите этот размер один раз - после загрузки страницы. А нужно - внутри обработчика события.

Comment: знал об этом, не знал как задать этот размер внутри обработчика.

Comment: @СтаниславСтрижаков Та же самая строчка, только непосредственно перед тем местом, где используется это значение.

Comment: еще раз спасибо, разобрался.